# sending files and folders from client to server

Tags: python, client-server

i wrote a python program that should copy files and folders from the client to the server.
i am having an issue with the server receiving the data, i think the problem is that the client is sending all the data before the server is able to srtucre it into folders and files. anybody has any solution?

SERVER

```
import socket
import os
import tqdm


def receive_file(c, name, path, file_size):
    # receiving the data and creating the local file in storage
    new_path = path + "/" + name
    with open(new_path, "wb") as f:
        bytes_read = c.recv(file_size)
        f.write(bytes_read)


def receive_folder(c, name, num_in, path):
    new_path = path + "/" + name
    os.mkdir(new_path)
    for i in range(num_in):
        item = c.recv(128).decode("utf-8")
        item = item.split("$")
        check = item[0]
        name1 = item[1]
        size = int(item[2])
        if check == "folder":
            receive_folder(c, name1, num_in, new_path)
        else:
            receive_file(c, name1, new_path, size)


def main():
    # making the socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
    s.listen()

    while True:
        # accepting a client
        c, address = s.accept()
        print("client connected...")
        c.send(bytes("connection successful...", "utf-8"))

        msg = c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        msg = msg.split("$")
        check = msg[0]
        name = msg[1]
        num_in = int(msg[2])
        path = r"storage"

        # checking if this is a file or a folder
        if check == "folder":
            receive_folder(c, name, num_in, path)
        else:
            receive_file(c, name, path, num_in)

        print("received :-)")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

CLIENT

```
import socket
import os


def is_folder(file_name):
    if os.path.isdir(r"storage/" + file_name):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def send_file(s, file_name, path):
    new_path = path + "/" + file_name
    file_size = os.path.getsize(new_path)
    s.send(("file" + "$" + file_name + "$" + str(file_size)).encode("utf-8"))

    with open(new_path, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            s.send(data)


def send_folder(s, folder_name, path):
    new_path = path + "/" + folder_name
    content = os.listdir(new_path)
    content_num = len(content)
    s.send(("folder" + "$" + folder_name + "$" + str(content_num)).encode("utf-8"))

    for i in range(content_num):
        if os.path.isfile(new_path + "/" + content[i]):
            send_file(s, content[i], new_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(new_path + "/" + content[i]):
            send_folder(s, content[i], new_path)


def main():
    # making the socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 8080))
    msg = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(msg)

    # getting the input saying what to transfer
    name = str(input("enter name:"))
    path = r"storage"

    # determining if the String is a file or a folder and
    # telling the server what it is
    if is_folder(name):
        send_folder(s, name, path)
    else:
        send_file(s, name, path)

    print("Data Sent Successfully :-)")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use REST for a use case like this? I think the easiest way to do this would be a simple Flask POST REST Endpoint to transfer the data this way.

Comment: im new to python so i wasn't familiar with this api

Comment: @Amit_Grimber,  are you open to solving this use case using Flask and REST?